# Unity gets stuck on Application.Reload when entering play mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am experiencing a very annoying bug with unity where whenever I try and enter play mode, it gets stuck on Application.Reload. I get this every time i enter play mode, however it stops being stuck on Application.Reload whenever i edit/add a file to the assets (e.g. adding whitespace to a random script, saving and reentering unity) and then it enters playmode fine. How can I fix this as it is very inconvenient to edit a script every time I want to test... I have tried on 2020.3.25f1 and upgraded to 2020.3.29f1 and the problem has persisted. It is also not exclusive to one projects but experienced in all of them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if there is any place in your project path that is not in English.
I had a parent folder on my project path that was written in Chinese, then I had the same problem as you, changed it into English and never encountered it again.

Comment: Thanks for your help but after a couple of days of experiencing the issue it went away... I have no idea why as I didnt change anything, just booted up my pc one day and it worked fine.

Comment: You're welcome, Unity has epilepsy from time to time